# jQuery draggable() element doesn't start till after the second tap (on double tap only), any explanation?

Tags: android, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-touch-punch

I have a draggable element that responses to a tap/touch event to be dragged on a slider. It works fine on iOS devices. But on Android, it only works if I second tap the slider's icon! I need it to work from the first tap.

I'm using the JQuery Touch Punch plugin already. here is my code

```js
$(".slider").draggable({
                    axis: "x",
                    containment: "parent"
                },
                        {
                            start: function () {
                                console.log("dragging started");
                            },
                            stop: function () {

                                sliderPos = $(".slider").css("left");
                                sliderPos = Number(sliderPos.replace("px", ""));

                                sizer = (Math.round((sliderPos / newSliderWidth) * 10) + 10) * 2;
                                $('.reader_text_container, .surah_title_item').css("font-size", sizer + "px");
                                saves.SetItem("font-size", sizer);
                                var thisHeight = $('.reader_title_top_bar_heading').outerHeight() + 'px';
                                $('.reader_text_bookmark').css("top", thisHeight);
                              }
                        });
```